# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Java heap space error while trying to build and deploy

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

My laptop is running Window 7 32bits. I am using Worklight 6.0.

I can code/modify and test for a while until a couple days ago when the function of build and deploy took a long time and finally errored out with a "Java heap space".

I tried expanding XMX from 512m to be 1g and XMS from 40m to be 512m in eclipse.ini,
but it still does not work.

Comment: if my answer below helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the memory given to the application server.

In Eclipse, open the Server view, expand the Worklight server and add the following to the jvm options: `-Xmx1024m`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to add/update the "**-Xmx1024m**" in **eclips.ini** as well, it worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and thank you for your answer, but: Isn't this already mentioned in the question?

Comment: ok yes but it should be clear enough that we requir to chnage values in both eclips.ini and jvm.opions